# Auto authenticate password protected server folder - Python

Tags: android, python, .htaccess

I have been working on an android app, which access the folder present in the server.
For security reasons, i protected the folder using .htaccess method.
It worked fine.
Now when i access the same folder using my webpage, it prompts for username and password. How to avoid that?

Can it be hardcoded?

Server Language:Python

Comment: Just to clarify... you want to bypass the _HTTP Authentication_ for when users access your site over _HTTP_?

Comment: Yes you are right. Do you have any ideas regarding that?

Comment: Well, my first thought is to not use HTTP authentication, but use some other kind of authentication for your Android app? However, if you are accessing the site from known IPs then you could perhaps make an exception for these IPs and only apply the HTTP authentication otherwise? How you do that could depend on your version of Apache.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What are the other authentication types for android app?